# Reading x264 bitstream using JM Reference

Tags: x264

I have encoded a video to a raw 264 bitstream using x264. JM decoder correctly decode the video. However, when I try to extract the modes and motion vectors of the macroblock by printing out the macroblock info, they print out the wrong values. Have anyone experience these before ?

Comment: Do you think it makes any sense, that the decoder inteprets x264 data incorrectly and still decodes it fine ?
What options do you use in x264 and JM ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified JM decoder to calculate and print the correct MVs and modes. I verified the result with videos encoded by JM itself. However, it does not work for .264 bitstream encoded by x264. But still, the video is decoded correctly.